# http post a map object using application/json content-type

Tags: rest, dart

I am encountering a problem trying to use the "package:http/http.dart' pub package to post some JSON data to a web service.  I have formatted the data correctly (which I confirmed by posting using the Advanced REST Client extension for Chrome) and the only difference is the Content-Type is forced to the wrong type (the web service only accepts "application/json"):

*If body is a Map, it's encoded as form fields using encoding. The content-type of the request will be set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; this cannot be overridden.*

The documentation suggests:

*For more fine-grained control over the request, use Request or StreamedRequest instead.*

Any examples of using either of these to HTTP POST with a Map for the body and Content-Type "application/json"?  I'm stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HttpRequest](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/dev/#dart-dom-html.HttpRequest) on client side :

```dart
HttpRequest.request(url, method: 'POST',
    requestHeaders:{'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
    sendData: '{"a":1}').then((r) => ....);
```

And [HttpClient](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/dev/#dart-io.HttpClient) on server side :

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
main() {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.postUrl(Uri.parse("...")).then((HttpClientRequest request) {
    request.headers.add('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
    request.write('{"a":1}');
    return request.close();
  }).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
    UTF8.decodeStream(response).then(print);
  });
}
```

Comment: dart:html is not available on the stand-alone VM

Comment: It was not mentioned in your question :)